# Why is it better to use synchronous programming for in-memory operations?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-multiprocessing, synchronous, in-memory

I have a complex nested data structure. I iterate through it and perform some calculations on each possible uniqe pair of elements. It's all in-memory mathematical functions. I don't read from files or do networking.

It takes a few hours to run, with `do_work()` being called 25,000 times. I am looking for ways to speed it up.

Although `Pool.map()` seems useful for my lists, it's proving to be difficult because I need to pass extra arguments into the function being mapped.

I thought using the Python `multitasking` library would help, but when I use `Pool.apply_async()` to call `do_work()`,  it actually takes longer.

I did some googling and [a blogger](https://medium.com/@adamhooper/node-synchronous-code-runs-faster-than-asynchronous-code-b0553d5cf54e) says **"Use sync for in-memory operations — async is a complete waste when you aren’t making blocking calls."** Is this true? Can someone explain why? Do the RAM read & write operations interfere with each other? Why does my code take longer with async calls? `do_work()` writes calculation results to a database, but it doesn't modify my data structure.

Surely there is a way to utilize my processor cores instead of just linearly iterating through my lists.

---

My starting point, doing it synchronously:

```
     main_list   = [ [ [a,b,c,[x,y,z], ... ], ... ], ... ] # list of identical structures
     helper_list = [1,2,3]
     z = 2
     for i_1 in range(0, len(main_list)):
         for i_2 in range(0, len(main_list)):
             if i_1 < i_2: # only unique combinations
                 for m in range(0, len(main_list[i_1])):
                     for h, helper in enumerate(helper_list):
                         do_work( 
                             main_list[i_1][m][0], main_list[i_2][m][0], # unique combo
                             main_list[i_1][m][1], main_list[i_1][m][2], 
                             main_list[i_1][m][3][z], main_list[i_2][m][3][h],
                             helper_list[h]
                         )
```

Variable names have been changed to make it more readable.

Comment: "_Do the RAM read & write operations interfere with each other?_" - Absolutely. There is only one system bus, no matter how many cores/CPUs you have.

Comment: What is `do_work` actually doing?

Answer (score 4):

This is just a general answer, but too long for a comment...

First of all, I think your biggest bottleneck at this very moment is Python itself. I don't know what `do_work()` does, but if it's CPU intensive, you have the GIL which completely prevents effective parallelisation inside one process. No matter what you do, threads will fight for the GIL and it will eventually make your code even slower. Remember: Python has real threading, but the CPU is shared inside a single process.
I recommend checking out the page of David M Beazley: http://dabeaz.com/GIL/gilvis who did a lot of effort to visualise the GIL behaviour in Python.

On the other hand, the module `multiprocessing` allows you to run multiple processes and "circumvent" the GIL downsides, but it will be tricky to get access to the same memory locations without bigger penalties or trade-offs.

Second: if you utilise heavy nested loops, you should think about using `numba` and trying to fit your data structures inside `numpy` (structured) arrays. This can give you order of magnitude of speed quite easily. Python is slow as hell for such things but luckily there are ways to squeeze out a **lot** when using appropriate libraries.

To sum up, I think the code you are running could be orders of magnitudes faster with `numba` and `numpy` structures.

Alternatively, you can try to rewrite the code in a language like `Julia` (very similar syntax to Python and the community is extremely helpful) and quickly check how fast it is in order to explore the limits of the performance. It's always a good idea to get a feeling how fast something (or parts of a code) can be in a language which has not such complex performance critical aspects like Python.

Answer (score 2):

Your task is more CPU bound than relying on I/O operations. Asynchronous execution make sense when you have long I/O operations i.e. sending/receiving something from network etc.

What you can do is split task to the chunks and utilize threads and multiprocessing (run on different CPU cores).